# Apply an effect to an Illustrator PathItem by scripting

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm creating graphic objects by scripting (javascript) with Illustrator CC and I would like to apply an effect to a `PathItem` element. I want a drop shadow effect whose I know parameter values.

The Illustrator documentation doesn't mention any function to apply effects, but when I look my object on the data inspector in the ExtendScript Toolkit window, I see my `PathItem` has a `applyEffect()` function, requiring one argument.

Does anyone know what kind of parameter this function requires and how to apply a drop shadow effect?

Seen [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448553/scripting-adobe-illustrator-how-to-apply-an-effect) but maybe it's possible since 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still no good news from 2020. As far as I can tell we have the same half-automated options:

- Manually make an AI file with styles. Then you can use a script to open the file and to copy styles (or styled objects) from there.
- Manually make an AIA file with an action that makes the style. Then you can invoke this action from your script.

Both the options lack the ability to set/change properties of the predefined styles on the run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one HTH,

```
documents[0].graphicStyles[1].applyTo(documents[0].selection[0]);
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks. It works for me with graphicStyles[0] only because my doc.graphicStyles has only one element which is a stroke effect. Maybe it's possible to add graphicStyles to this list but I don't know why.